# Bones for a Crow final objective glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am attempting to complete *Bones for a Crow*, the bounty you can get from the innkeeper at the Bee and Barb in Riften, and get the dragonplate armor. However, when I kill Crowstooth—solidly inside the tower, no less—her Forsworn mates, the draugr, and the Elder Dragon that always spawns, all I ever find at the top is a large chest (unlocked), then up the stairs, a skeleton with a few gold and occasionally a bone meal. There's also a pedestal above the skeleton that always has a copy of *Withershins*. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check this: https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bones_for_a_Crow
Do you have mods installed?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Yeah, that's where I heard about killing Crowstooth. And no mods. I'm playing on Nintendo Switch, if that helps.